# Реализация счётчика кликов в приложении андроид

Tags: android, mysql

Подскажите , как сделать счётчик кликов в приложении?

**Тема такова:** *Приложение отображает картинки и текст соединяясь с сервером и имеет две активности*

`CategoryAPI = Config3.ADMIN3_PANEL_URL + "/api/get-all-category-data.php" +"?accesskey="+Config3.AccessKey+"&category_id=";`

**Прослушиватель событий для обработки списка при нажатии**

```
listCategory1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // перейти к странице меню
        Intent iActivityCategoryList = new Intent(ActivityCategoryList1.this, ActivityCategoryList.class);
        iActivityCategoryList.putExtra("category_id", Category1_ID.get(position));

        startActivity(iActivityCategoryList);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
    }
});
```

**Метод для анализа данных json с сервера**

```
public void parseJSONData(){

        clearData();

        try {
            // запрашивать данные из API категории
            URL url = new URL(Category1API);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(20000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(20000);
            connection.connect();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            String str = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null){
                str += line;
            }
            // анализировать данные json и хранить в переменных arraylist
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
            JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = data.getJSONObject(i);

                JSONObject category = object.getJSONObject("Category1");

                Category1_ID.add(Long.parseLong(category.getString("Category1_ID")));
                Category1_name.add(category.getString("Category1_name"));
                Category1_image.add(category.getString("Category1_image"));


            }


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            IOConnect = 0;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**А это адаптер активности**

```
// adapter class for custom category list
class AdapterCategoryList1 extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public AdapterCategoryList1(Activity act) {
        this.activity = act;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(act);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ActivityCategoryList1.Category1_ID.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public AdapterCategoryList1(Activity activity, List<ActivityCategoryList1> testData) {

    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category1_list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.txtText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtText);
        holder.imgThumb = (pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgThumb);


        //imageLoader.DisplayImage(Constant.AdminPageURL+ActivityCategoryList1.Category1_image.get(position), holder.imgThumb);
        Picasso.with(activity).load(Config3.ADMIN3_PANEL_URL + "/" + ActivityCategoryList1.Category1_image.get(position)).placeholder(R.drawable.loading).into(holder.imgThumb);
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtText;
        ImageView imgThumb;
    }



}
```

**Как я могу считывать клики по картинке и отправлять эти цифры в базу данных на сервере под идентификатор этой картинки с возможностью синхронного обновления количества кликов?**

Comment: Так на image можно же добавить `.clickListener`. Вы получаете текущее кол-во кликов, а при нажатии на фотку - взять это кол-во и добавить +1, отправить. Или я что-то не понял?

Comment: @MakoStorm - Вы не могли бы в развёрнутой форме описать ваш пример? Форму отправки и добавление в image  `.clickListener` ...

Comment: @MakoStorm - Сама реализация метода интересует, Может есть какой  нибудь исходник где это используется? Поиск в интернете не дал особой информации , нашёл только счётчик ворон...

Comment: У меня была ситуация, когда надо было показывать популярность конкретной новости. Дефолт значение популярности = 0. При нажатии я получаю это значение и делаю +1. Если популярность = 10, при нажатии будет 11. Ну и после операции додавания я отправляю в БД новое значение. Вам сделать аналогично. Прилепить листенер к изображению и при нажатии делать операцию додавания и отправки на сервер.

Comment: @MakoStorm - Что то я ни как не пойму такую реализацию. Так как  имеется ещё класс BaseAdapter для первой активности. У вас не осталось исходника , вашей ситуации ? Если да , то опубликуйте его в виде ответа пожалуйста, попробую его адаптировать.

Comment: Я делал это с помощью firebase, поэтому, думаю, вам мой код не сильно поможет. Адаптер для RecyclerView ?

Comment: @MakoStorm - я добавил исходник адаптера к вопросу , посмотрите выше.

Comment: Вот, к примеру. У Вас есть imgThumb. Можно добавить к этому изображению листенер. При нажатии получить значение, добавить +1 и отправить на сервер.